# NoClassDefFoundError for third party libraries

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, command-line, noclassdeffounderror

I successfully build and run my application in IntelliJ using Gradle plugin
My dependencies described as

```
dependencies{
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    ...
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2"
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2"
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:2.0"
    ...
}
```

When I run my app from command line I get an error message:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     org/apache/commons/configuration2/ex/ConfigurationException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration2.ex.ConfigurationException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Run your gradle build with --debug 
It will output the reason it failed to add the jar to the classpath, if it didn't find the jar version in the maven repository or if you're running an offline build, maybe it was not found in the local jar folder.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to add the jars you are dependent on on your classpath, or

2) package your project by creating a jar with dependencies